# Facebook app fetching ads reports from business account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I can't figure this out, I hope someone here can point me in the right direction. I've searched for an answer but was unable to find it.

I want to create a Facebook app which would manage ads (download ads reports and statistics). I've got user account, registered as developer, created and whitelisted the app. I've got only Development Access and that means means I can query only ad accounts owned by the admins of the app, set up in the account list associated with your application.

Problem is that the account with ads is a business account so I can't add this account as part of developers team and get the statistics. I get permissions errors when trying to access the business account (I have access token and everything, it just won't let me see the ads data due to insufficient permissions).

Is there a way to do this without applying for Basic access (not sure if I'll get it since the app is not done)? Can't I really somehow connect my developer's account with that business account?

About access limits: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/access/v2.2#limits

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is working correctly - you can build and test the app against accounts administered by your app's admins/developers at first

Once it's working you can submit it for approval to the Basic access level, where you can manage more accounts, including those belonging to users who aren't admins/developers of the app

There's more information about the access levels and how to move between them in the [Access levels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/access) dovumentation

Comment: It seemed a bit odd to me that I am unable to test this on my own account only because it's a business one.